# What clustering algorithm is best for dataset with only binary categorical features

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, spectral-clustering

I have a dataset with a lot of binary categorical features and a single continuous target value.
I would like to cluster them but I am not quite sure what to use?

I have in the past used dbscan for something similar and it worked well, but that dataset also had lots of continuous features.

Do you have any tips and suggestions?

Would you suggest matrix factorization and then cluster?

Thank you very much!